# Google chrome - удалить breakpoint

Tags: google-chrome

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в Хроме удалить срабатывание точки остановки ?
Как только запускаю "инструмент разработчика" - сразу срабатывает точка остановки на какой то строчке. Ни закрытие, ни перезагрузка компа не помогают.

Comment: нажать на красный кружочек? Хотя может быть Вы открываете "инструменты разработчика" на каком-то специфическом сайте, где разработчики сами не любят отлаживать и заложили антиотладочные механизмы.

Comment: @KoVadim, не, это я что-то нажал и теперь вот такая засада. До этого все было нормально. И прикол в том, что этого красного кружочка теперь не появляется. Никак не могу остановить этот дебаггинг.